# excel csv file created via java cannot be imported by a third party

Tags: excel, csv, import

I have got a piece of code which generates csv files via Java. There is not problem in creating. However the client is complaining that they cannot import it into their application. They say if they open the csv file generated and re-save it then the application imports it fine.

I have also asked them to give me a sample csv file so I can compare it with the one I generated. They are exactly in the same format. When I open both of them, I can see both are (Comma Delimited) (*.csv). When I open them in notepad and notepad++, I just see data with no extra marks in them.

Sorry as I do not much have to provide. I am just wondering if anyone has come across with the same situation and found a solution.

Comment: There's really not much help to offer if we don't know the client application and it's actual problem importing your file. The only thing that could differ if the files "look" the same is the encoding and a (missing) BOM.

Comment: i was using \n for the new line, it should have been \r\n.. Sorted the problem out. Thanks for the comment Filburt!